# Does Mailman have an API or an export lists, users and owners option?

Tags: python, api, mailman

I am trying to migrate a legacy mailing list to a new web forum software and was wondering if mailman has an export option or an API to get all lists, owners, members and membership types.

Answer (score 4):

probably too late, but the list_members LISTNAME command (executed from a shell) will give you all the members of a list.

list_admins LISTNAME will give you the owners
What do you mean by membership type? list_members does have an option to filter on digest vs non-digest members. I don't think there's a way to get the moderation flag without writing a script for use with withlist

Answer (score 4):

This is really late as well, but I've been using [this script](http://fog.ccsf.edu/~msapiro/mailman-subscribers.py) for a while to get a mailing list's subscribers.

Like it says in the script, it uses the web interface to get all the members, which is quite handy since I don't have access to mailman's command line tools (shared hosting).

As it is right now, it'll only give you the members, but you can probably extend it to suit your needs.

Comment: I've tried the script (from the same location) and it returns 'Invalid password'. The password works in a browser. Mailman 2.1.14, python 2.6/2.7. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried out that script and I was also getting "Invalid password" till I changed the ``member_url`` and ``options_url`` on (lines 284, 285 respectively) to use https instead of http (my mailman is served up via https). Hope that helps.

Comment: spot on. In the meantime I was very impatient and made my own script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of bolt on API plugins and packages implemented in PHP. [PHP Mailman Interface](http://php-mailman.sourceforge.net/)